# Can't load Live Chat plugin with onclick

Tags: jquery, wordpress, livechat

I installed [Live Chat](http://supsystic.com/plugins/live-chat/) WP plugin, in their settings they give you multiple options on how to fire it, it works if I pick on page opening but if I want to tie it to an onclick event it gives me an error.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: lcsShowChat
```

This is the simple code snippet they suggest you to use:

```
<h1 onclick="lcsShowChat(1); return false;">Chat</h1>
```

Their support said that it doesn't show because the script isn't pre-loaded, something that isn't really clear in their instructions:

[image]

And they don't seem to give further assistance.

Any idea on why it tells me it can't find the script? Or how can I pre-load it so it shows when clicking? Thank you.

Live link with the "chat" button: http://ttapple.com

**EDIT**
After loading the scripts in the head of the page the initial issue seems solved but a new console error shows up:

```
function lcsShowChat( engineId ) {
    var engine = g_lcsChats.getByIngineId( engineId );
    if(engine) {
        engine.showChat();
    } else
        console.log('CAN NOT FIND ENGINE FOR CHAT '+ engineId+ ' !!!');
}
```

Comment: If you look in the network tab of developer tools: as the page loads, does the javascript file load successfully before you click?  Also, does the error pop up when the page loads, or when you click the object?

Comment: No, it does not load on network tab and error appears after I click

Comment: What about my other question?  Does the error pop up when the page loads, or when you click the object?

Comment: when you click the object

Comment: That's pretty odd.  Glad my questions helped you, I'm not sure I know of a better way with the information you've provided.  Perhaps you should include your <head> region in your question so we can see your script includes.

Comment: actually it still doesn't work, see edit

Comment: What is the new message that you receive?  You show the javascript but not the error.

Comment: just that "CAN NOT FIND ENGINE FOR CHAT 1 !!!" in the console log

Comment: Perhaps the live chat plugin documentation has a little more about setting up a chat engine.  I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that you didn't actually loaded chat core on server side: you just inserted JavaScript code - but it can't load all required core data from server. You need to use shortcode instead of JavaScript:

```
<a href="[supsystic-show-chat id=1]"></a>
```

or, if you are inserting this in your theme php files - use next code:

```
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[supsystic-show-chat id=1]');?>"></a>
```